# If user does not have a vibrator how to ensure app still visible on app store given vibrate permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-vibration

I have the following permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

but on some phones there is no vibrator so a call to `Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);` will return null.  so a crash can take place. Also my question is if i hold the permission above as is, will google play state that my app is not available to the users device because they do not hold vibrator hardware ?

What if i changed the permissions to this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false" />
```

will this allow the user to see the device on the play store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i hold the permission above as is, will google play state that my app is not available to the users device because they do not hold vibrator hardware ?

No, as `VIBRATE` is not [a permission that implies any feature requirements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

> What if i changed the permissions to this:

That would be useless, as [there is no `android:required` attribute on `<uses-permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html).